What is the word for the sky opposite the sunset?
This question landed me here on this site. I’ve Googled, looked on Reddit, Quora, looked in Websters, Encarta, and asked people I know, but haven’t found any satisfying (to me, anyway) answers. I’ve heard anti-solar sky, antipodal sky, others. Boo. It’s two words for one thing, and for another sounds like something Spock would say. Factual but you don’t want to dance with it. I like Spock but don’t let that guy name stuff.
I’m looking at the sunset. Now I’m turning directly around to behold the ______ .
I want to suggest glowback.
Sample sentence:
“I enjoy taking in the glowback before hitting the sack.”
What do you think? Come up with something better. This phenomenon deserves a word from you.

crepuscular glow, perhaps? Also, maybe there's a technical term in physics for this phenomenon.

'the Belt of Venus' per UNCOVERING SECRETS OF EARTH'S SHADOW
BY: BOB KING MARCH 2, 2022. [skyandtelescope.org] I've forgotten how to link, sorry, or it just never works; IDK.

https://skyandtelescope.org/astronomy-blogs/explore-night-bob-king/uncovering-secrets-of-earths-shadow/
